# Where is the ground wire connection of this DF electric TR28 transformer?

Tags: transformer, ac

I am trying to repurpose an old transformer I had lying around to use it with a stand mixer from the US (120V) here in Europe (220V). However, when looking at the label I noticed that it has a ground connection for the output side but none for the input side. Input side is the top of the picture, output the bottom.

[image]

Am I missing something? Is it okay to simply connect those 2 wires to the mains plug, hence the wall?

Furthermore, is this transformer rated for a big load such as a stand mixer? The model I will be using is a 350 watt model.

Comment: Why do you assume there'd be 2 PE connections? Most electronics only has 1. Once the chassis is grounded, it's grounded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Transformers don't naturally use or need a ground wire unless the insulation between the unsafe primary voltage and the supposedly safer secondary is sub-standard or not up to today's standards. On the basis that yours has a ground wire I expect it is quite an old model or has the earth for some form of EMC barrier.

> *Furthermore, is this transformer rated for a big load such as a stand
> mixer? The model I will be using is a 350 watt model.*

Your transformer only appears to be rated for a VA  of 120 and this means it shouldn't be used for a load of more than 120 watts.

Take note about which winding is primary and which is secondary: -

[image]

In other words, it is the upper port in your picture that is the primary (just in case you were not aware). Picture from [here](http://www.apecokuwait.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/TR28-transformer.pdf). And note that if you apply 220 volts to the "0" and "230" terminals, there's a good chance that there will be 460 volts AC produced on the "460" terminal. Just saying in case you didn't realize.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

*Figure 1. The transformer has one ground connection. Since all terminals are occupied on the primary side the ground terminal uses one of the spare terminals on the secondary side.*

If "neutralising" of the secondary is required a jumper can be added between SEC 0 and the ground terminal.

Best case VA rating is 120 VA. You have a 350 W load which is 350 VA (if power factor is unity) so it is not adequate for your load.

Answer (score 3):

Not going to work.

You are trying to power a 350W load with 120VA transformer.

Even if you did connect the grounds, the output of the secondary would not be ground reference.

If you have to use kitchen appliances with voltages they are not supposed to, get a proper device for using it safely.

Answer (score 2):

By the look of it the transformer is connected correctly in the picture. The ground wire (yellow\green) is connected to the ground terminal (which should only be connected to the chassis).

Here is a wiring diagram for the transformer (although this is not for the specific voltage of the secondary side that you have so you'll have to look at your model #):

[image: The next thing you need to do is figure out if]
Source: https://www.tme.eu/Document/bb7651643ff3fce400f23ff9a881686a/tr28.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Even if this transformer had adequate power rating (it doesn't):

If you're using such a transformer, you must follow the wiring diagram on the label. Those brace-looking things (`[`) on the label are not decorative: they depict links that you must add to configure the output for 115V operation. And no, just because the voltmeter shows that the two terminals you're using have 115V between them doesn't mean that it's OK. When used as you show, the secondary has only 1/2 of the power rating of the transformer - i.e. only a measly 60VA!

The secondaries - yes, there are two of them - must be connected in parallel - and you didn't do that, by the look of it.

[image: a depiction of the relationship between the symbols and the terminals]

See [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/579956/10810) for details of the parallel connection. There need to be two links: one between 3,4, andother between 1,2, with terminals numbered starting at 1 on the right.